# Why are abaqus contact stresses inconsistent?

Tags: contacts, abaqus

I may be missing something very basic in abaqus while modeling here. I have two bodies next to other (lets assume two bars placed adjacent to each other) and I have mentioned a surface to surface contact between the two crossectional areas in contact. I have fixed the other end of one bar and provided a displacement of say 0.1 on the other bar to observe the contact stresses. Now I expect the stresses to be identical on the two bars but that is not what I am observing. I see that the bar which is fixed experiencing the stresses but no stresses are seen on the bar with the displacement boundary condition. I think I am missing something while modeling this simple case. Any thought?[Here is a screenshot of the assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJATI.jpg). When I run a static analysis with upperbody fixed at its base and a small displacement in Y direction to the lower body, I expect the contact to be detected (which is observed) but I also expect he stresses to be similar on both the bodies. But what I am getting is that the stress and deformation is generated on the upper body and the lower one shows negligible stresses

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a picture or a better explanation. Currently the question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I have edited the question and added an image of the assembly.

Comment: Thanks, (a more useful image might be the stresses in the odb). In abaqus contact, there is a master and a slave surface, which dictates whether you say surface A is penetrating surface B or you say surface B is penetrating surface A. Also you can define the second surface as a node region or a surface.

Comment: The problem you are solving is quite difficult, as contact is limited to a very small contact area (initially a point). If you are doing this to understand contact, then you might consider looking at a a flat bottomed rod hitting a larger flat surface. Also using tet elements or hex elements in 3D  (tri or quad in 2D) will handle contact differently.

Comment: Agreed but I was not looking to achieve accuracy for time being. I was happy as long as the contact is detected and does not generate spurious data. I think I have found an answer to my question. Its actually dependent on the boundary condition I mention. For the lower part, when I assign the upward displacement on the surface in contact, it doesnot generate stress on that part. when I assign a displacement of the bottom surface of the lower part which is not in contact with the upper, then the model generates equal and opposite stress on both the parts. Will look into why this should happen .

Answer (score 0):

The result of contact also depends on the solution strategy you are using. If you are using Penalty method, you may experience high oscillation and the contact surface is not detected correctly. For a robust and stable contact, you can switch to using Augmented Lagragian method. Try first with small increment to see if some contact forces are produced, then you can increase the prescribed displacement.